Map values from a list to a filtered list



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G




1
Brand A
Product 01
600

Product 01
US
online


2
Brand A
Product 02
100

Product 02
NL
local shop


3
Brand A
Product 02
300

Product 03
AT
online


4
Brand B
Product 01
400

Product 04
FR
local shop


5
Brand B
Product 03
500






6
Brand C
Product 02
200






7
Brand C
Product 02
800

Brand C




8
Brand C
Product 04
900

Product 02
NL
local shop


9
Brand C
Product 01
700

Product 04
FR
local shop


10
Brand D
Product 03
250

Product 01
US
online


11
Brand D
Product 03
460






12
Brand D
Product 04
690








In the table above I have two different lists:
List A = Range A1:C12 
List B = Range E1:G4 (Info: The products in this list will be always unique)
In Range E8:E10 the List A gets filtered with this formula:
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B;A:A=E7))

All this works.

Now, in Range F8:G10 I want to add additional information to the filtered products from List B. 
So far I am able to do this for the first row with this formula:
=DROP(FILTER(E1:G4;E1:E4=E8);;1)

How do I need to change the formula(s) to make it work for all rows?

If order does not matter we can nest the filters:
=FILTER(E1:G4,ISNUMBER(MATCH(E1:E4,UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E7)),0)))


If order matters then we use DROP(REDUCE())
=DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E7)),LAMBDA(z,y,VSTACK(z,XLOOKUP(y,$E$1:$E$4,$E$1:$G$4)))),1)



Just puzzling a bit for fun:

Formula in E8:
=LET(f,FILTER(B:B,A:A=E7),TAKE(SORTBY(E1:G4,XMATCH(E1:E4,f)),ROWS(UNIQUE(f))))

